# Installed new Moodle theme and everything screwed up

Tags: moodle

I installed a new moodle theme ('adaptable' to be exact) on my local machine but then it asked me to upgrade a couple of things which I did. Now I can't even see my login page. I copied everything from the server as well (and changed the config.php file to old settings) but still cant see the login page.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: I used '$CFG->allowthemechangeonurl = true;' in the config.php file and passed the theme name as argument, the login page came up. But when I login, I see this screen [see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3reSt.png). This is exactly what came up earlier and when I clicked on "Upgrade Moodle Database", everything got messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed the theme plugin from the code base? From looking at your photo it appears you have.

If so you can click "Upgrade Moodle Database" and it will uninstall the adaptable theme. The word 'Upgrade' is misleading in Moodle. It really refers to any changes in the version files including the removal of a plugin.